# How to write a command in plink using delphi 7

Tags: postgresql, delphi, ssh, delphi-7, plink

Need to be guided. I wanna make an application that can connect to postgre database through ssh server. My idea is to make a connection using plink => login to ssh2 server => login to database postgre => do some query (select ... from...) => get the result => show the result in table.

I get dificulties to build connection using plink since we need to write a username, password, etc. in interactive mode. I have no idea to do it by using Delphi 7, especially to pass a string (for example password) to existing plink.

Any better or easier advice are welcome.

Comment: It might help to look through the source of [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/). It is open source and can connect via plink.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use an ssh lib rather than an external process? Do you have any code?

Comment: @DavidA, i tried heidiSQL but unfortunately couldn't find SSH Tunneling for Postgres. heidiSQL support SSH Tunneling for SQL, as i already tried.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, i already searched free ssh library but not found yet so far. if you know one please advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Team for all great support, especially @DavidHeffernan for the advice (use ssh library).

Finally, i tried chilkat ssh library to connect to my ADO Connection. Problem solved.